# Load static class in appdomain

Tags: c#, appdomain, static-class

I'm met with a big problem in C# AppDomain.

I need to load a static class in a .dll file and execute its method:

1. When I try to load them by

   ```
   Assembly.LoadFrom("XXXXX") // (XXXXX is the full path of dll)
   ```

   the .dll will not be unload automatically or programmatically.
2. When I try to load them in AppDomain like

   ```
   adapterDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AdapterDomain");
   (a)adapterDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(this.AdapterFilePath, this.AdapterFullName);
   (b)adapterAssembly=adapterDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(this.AdapterFilePath));
   ```

   If I use method (a), because the target class is a static one, it doesn't work.

   If I use method (b), because the target .dll is not the same directory with my project, I will get an exception.

How can I load the .dll and the static class, and then unload the .dll after my usage?

Comment: Have you read through this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx

Comment: You can't unload a DLL. You can unload the AppDomain

Comment: But I can't add a static class in the DLL to AppDomain..

Comment: After reading Josh's link, I didn't found way to solve my problem, methods introduced in this article are all about normal class, but I want to load a static class to AppDomain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method (b) fails because [AppDomain.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wcywcds.aspx) cannot resolve assemblies that are not in the base app dir, the probing private paths or the GAC.

Also note that the `AppDomain.Load` is **not** loading the assembly on the specific AppDomain (like `adapterDomain.Load` in your sample code). Instead it is loading it on the current AppDomain (this is the one making the call to `AppDomain.Load`. This behavior is remarked on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wcywcds.aspx).) Apparently this is not what you are looking for.

Here's an example on how to call a static method in the child AppDomain:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This is for testing purposes!
        var loadedAssembliesBefore = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ChildDomain");                        
        // This will make the call to the static method in the dhild AppDomain.
        domain.DoCallBack(LoadAssemblyAndCallStaticMethod);
        // Print the loaded assemblies on the child AppDomain. This is for testing purposes!
        domain.DoCallBack(PrintLoadedAssemblies);
        AppDomain.Unload(domain);

        // This is for testing purposes!
        var loadedAssembliesAfter = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        // Assert that no assembly was leaked to the main AppDomain.
        Debug.Assert(!loadedAssembliesBefore.Except(loadedAssembliesAfter).Any());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    // Loads StaticMethodInHere.dll to the current AppDomain and calls static method 
    // StaticClass.DoSomething.  
    static void LoadAssemblyAndCallStaticMethod()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY");

        assembly.GetType("CLASS_CONTAINING_STATIC_METHOD")
                .InvokeMember("STATIC_METHOD", 
                              BindingFlags.Public | 
                              BindingFlags.Static | 
                              BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                              null, 
                              null, 
                              null);
    }

    // Prints the loaded assebmlies in the current AppDomain. For testing purposes.
    static void PrintLoadedAssemblies()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("/ Assemblies in {0} -------------------------------",
                          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);

        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
        }            
    }
}
```

To make this work you will need to replace:

- PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY with the path of the assembly containing the static method including the extension.
- CLASS_CONTAINING_STATIC_METHOD with the name of the class containing the static method including the namespace of the class.
- STATIC_METHOD with the name of the static method.

Note that the `BindingFlags` are set for public static methods.

Comment: Yes, it works well with your method, but one more thing should be noticed: the method which define the AppDomain must be static mothod.

Comment: @WenchaoYou It doesn't have to be a static method. You could have an intermediate object, created in the child AppDomain, that does the loading. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17324102/850119

Comment: Yeah! I've got that by following your guidance and MSDN page 【[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback.aspx)】 the third case, thank you so much