# Pattern for creating multiple instances of static class

Tags: c#, static

I have legacy dll (code is not available). In this dll there is static class that connects to remote PC by IP.
The available code enables connection to single IP at a time.

The problem:
I need to connect to multiple IP's at the same time from same runtime.

Is there trivial way to do so without creating seperate `AppDomain` for each instance?

In other words - Is there a pattern that "cancels" `static` objects?

Tahnk you

Comment: you can't create an instance of a static class... can't you decompile the dll?

Comment: Different AppDomain? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782448/125740

Comment: Can we use reflection?

Comment: No you can't create an instance of a static class, but propably you can create a new static class at runtime with reflection and clone all methods and properties. Not sure if works for static, but you can take an idea from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-create-dynamically-a-class-in-c

Comment: Thank you for your comment: @ZoharPeled - I Must use the original dll (company's policy).

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti - I'll give it a try just for the sport. Thank you