# "Could Not Load File or Assembly" error when referencing project DLLs in new AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain

I'm receiving this error "Could not load file or assembly 'MyReferenceAssembly', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." when attempting to load a reference to another custom DLL.

```
AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
domainSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myCustomDomain", null, domainSetup);

Type compilerType = typeof(MyCustomObject);
MyCustomObject cr = (MyCustomObject)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(compilerType.Assembly.Location, compilerType.FullName);


List<AssemblyName> references = compilerType.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().ToList();
    references.ForEach(r => domain.Load(r));
```

I have tried not loading the references but still encounter the same error.  It does seem to successfully load any references that are in the GAC.

Do i need to load references into this domain?  And if so, how do i load custom library references into a new AppDomain?

Comment: I've had a mini breakthrough.  I've found that by loading the entire AppDomainSetup from the current domain into the new domain it works.

AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
domainSetup = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation;

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Remember that AppDomain.Load loads the assembly in the current AppDomain and NOT in the AppDomain referenced by the "domain" variable.

Comment: I'm attempting to load all the referenced DLLs into the new AppDomain, referenced by the domain variable, in order to allow the code to execute in an isolated domain.

Comment: You could start with something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225276/create-custom-appdomain-and-add-assemblies-to-it/17324102#17324102 but you could also use the AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly method if you want to run an executable.