# Replace DLL dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, appdomain

I use `VCProjectEngine.dll`, and there are 2 versions for `Visual Studio 2010` and `Visual Studio 2012`.
I want to replace the `DLL` versions *dynamically* i would unload the old version, and then to load the new `DLL`.

I understood from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain) that I can't unload `DLL`, but unload all *domain*.
So I try to unload the domain:

```
AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", adevidence, domaininfo);

AppDomain.Unload(domain);
```

and now I try to load the new `DLL` version:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"));
```

but it didn't help, `Visual Studio 2012` doesn't know the `VCProject` type, because the old version is incorrect for it.

What's wrong in my code? or maybe there is other way to replace the `DLL` programmatically?

Comment: Note that you should not use AppDomain.Load for this purpose. Have a look at this answer on how to load assemblies in a specific AppDomain http://stackoverflow.com/a/17324102/850119.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you can't unload DLLs -you can unload app-domains.

However, for unloading app-domains to work, you need to load the DLL *in the domain you are unloading*. In your example, you're unloading some app-domain, then loading the DLL in your app's default domain.

You should load the DLL inside that domain, and call its methods there. Note you'll need all your return values and arguments to be serializable, as they will be marshaled. This also means the objects exposed by your DLLs should be `MarshalByRef` objects.

Comment: so, I need to replace `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load` with `domain.Load`?

Comment: Yes. And you need to call the DLL across domain boundries.

Comment: How I call the DLL? I just want to declare static type of interface that exist in the DLL, like `VCProject pro=solution.Projects.Item(1).Object;`

Comment: You create an instance of a class in the DLL. That's what I meant by 'call the DLL'. All access to that instance will be across domain boundries.

Comment: The problem is that those types exist in the old dll and in the new  both, and the debugger take the class which appear in the old dll,  instead of the new one.

Comment: How are you instantiating that class? You should use `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`

Comment: You are right, but I need to create static type of **interface**, so when I use `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` I get an error `Constructor on type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCProject' not found.`

Comment: You can't create an instance of an interface, and interfaces do not have static members. You need to create an instance of a class and cast it to an interface.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to create a **dynamic** type, but **static** type. like the example above: I put the `solution.Projects.Item(1).Object` in `VCPoject`- interface type.